# Interlinking css with php

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to get a php function to only happen once a css style happened.

For example when my screen is 800px wide then that specific php function must happen.

Is there a way to do that?
And if so how do you go about doing it?

Comment: You cant call `PHP` via `CSS`, use `javascript` instead

Comment: PHP is executed on your server before the user receives the page, CSS is executed on your user's PC, which happens after the page leaves the server.

Comment: What are you *really* intending to do? PHP is executed when someone requests a page from your web browser. That someone may not even *have* a screen, and you certainly can't tell if they have and what the resolution is unless you wrote the code that makes the request and made it report it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Tera-WURFL](http://dbapi.scientiamobile.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), a PHP & MySQL-based software package that detects mobile devices and their features.

The code to detect the browser width in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("TeraWurfl.php");
$wurflObj = new TeraWurfl();
$wurflObj->GetDeviceCapabilitiesFromAgent();
$browser_width = $wurflObj->capabilities['display']['max_image_width'];
// Also, you can get the display resolution
$display_width = $wurflObj->capabilities['display']['resolution_width'];
?>
```